# Error:(51, 6) 'zzE' overrides nothing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm getting error overriding the zzE function in kotlin.
Below is the code showing the error.

```
override fun zzE(intent: Intent): Boolean {
        try {
            val count = 3

            ShortcutBadger.applyCount(applicationContext, count)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return super.zzE(intent)

        }
```

Below is the error:

> Error:(51, 6) 'zzE' overrides nothing

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: The function `zzE` overrides nothing, there is no `zzE` function in its parent.

Comment: What function are you trying to override here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error:(51, 6) 'zzE' overrides nothing
```

> [**`overrides`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Override.html)  Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override
>   a method declaration in a supertype.

**`REASON`**

- The method does override or implement a method declared in a
  supertype.
- The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any
  public method declared in Object.

**`EXAMPLE`**

```
interface setYourName{

    fun onLock(status: Boolean)
}
```

Now showing **`overrides nothing`** Error, Due to Argument mismatch.

```
override fun onLock(status: String)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the dependency from

**implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0"**

to

**implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6"**

working now.
Thanks guys

Comment: OMG! Any way, Move ahead. I thought another

Comment: By the way any idea why version 11.0.0 doesn't support the zzE function tho ?

Comment: Didn't use yet. My answer depends on LOGIC. May be have  alternate way.

Comment: Ayd.Thanks  @ IntelliJ